# Postfix Relay Based on Recepient

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp

What is the best practice when one has to implement this sort of ruleset in postfix?

- Email sent to `a@example.com`, `b@example.com`, etc ought to be relayed to `smtp.a.example.com`.
- Email sent to `[everyone else]@example.com` ought to be relayed to `smtp.b.example.com`.

Ideally this shouldn't depend on the content of the message - just the `RCPT TO` SMTP command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [transport_maps and relayhost](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) feature from postfix. Edit **main.cf**, and add this two lines

```
relayhost = smtp.b.example.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transportmaps
```

The above file (/etc/postfix/transportmaps) should contain something like:

```
a@example.com  smtp.a.example.com
b@example.com  smtp.a.example.com
```

Don't forget to [postmap](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html) that file.